# Webpack Missing Module 'Module Not Found'

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I'm currently working on a react webpack babel etc site and trying to build the first time. The build is successful, but when I open up the browser I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "/Users/michael.nakayama/Documents/Development/jamsesh/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/node-libs-browser/node_modules/process/browser.js"
```

This module exists. Going to that actual url in my browser shows the file in question. But I cannot figure out why webpack cannot find it. I don't know if this is a babel6 issue or a webpack issue, or neither. My config file looks like this:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var cleanWebpack = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

var ignore = new webpack.IgnorePlugin(new RegExp("/(node_modules|ckeditor)/"))

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: './lib/client/entry',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public/js',
    filename: 'app.js',
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8081/js/',
  },
  plugins: [
    ignore,
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js'],
    moduleDirectories: ['./node_modules']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        loaders: ['babel-loader?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015,plugins[]=transform-es2015-classes,plugins[]=transform-react-jsx'],
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and my webpack server file is as follows:

```
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');

var webpack = require('webpack');
var config = require('../../webpack.config');

var server = new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
  // webpack-dev-server options
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  stats: { colors: true },
});

server.listen(8081, 'localhost', function() {});
```

and here are the packages I have installed:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.3.17",
    "babel-core": "^6.3.26",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "body-parser": "^1.14.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.5",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "history": "^1.17.0",
    "jade": "^1.11.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.8.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pg": "^4.4.3",
    "react": "^0.14.6",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "react-router": "^1.0.3",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  }
```

entry.js:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var routes = require('../routes');

// -v x.13.x
/**Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function (Handler, state) {
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.getElementById('react-app'));
});**/

var node = document.getElementById('react-app');
// -v 1.0.0
ReactDOM.render(<Router history={createBrowserHistory()} routes={routes}/> , node);
```

Also as a heads up, I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling all my packages. I have tried installing specifically the node-libs-browser modules. thanks.

Comment: Try remove node_modules and after: "npm cache clean && npm install"

Comment: @DmitryYaremenko didn't work. I had already tried that. But I did it again to verify. Still no success.

Comment: What about lib/client/entry.js? Or try to run with only console.log('hello')

Comment: Need more information. Tried your configs on empty projects - it works. So, problem in some module inside entry or npm/node/webpack version incompatibility

Comment: I added entry.js the error that I'm getting occurs just from require('react'). Debugging the console took me all the way down to ReactDOM which is where it blew up.

Comment: furthermore, changing the entry.js to console.log('wow'); did nothing :(

Comment: Why you need Ignore plugin on node_modules ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem with ignore plugin on `node_modules`. In `webpack.config.js`, you have:

```
var ignore = new webpack.IgnorePlugin(new RegExp("/(node_modules|ckeditor)/"))
...
plugins: [
  ignore,
],
```

From [Ignore Plugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#ignoreplugin) documentation:

> Don’t generate modules for requests matching the provided RegExp.

Webpack tries to `require` module with the name `node_modules/process/browser` for React module and fails with it because it is ignored.

Try to remove `node_modules` from Ignore Plugin or write less global condition if you really need this.

Comment: YOU ARE A GOD. I had this in a previous project with an older version of pretty much all my packages and it was fine. But removing that works. Thanks you so much.

Comment: thank you so much, never thought of this scenario. everything was so clear but I don't see it :(

Answer (score 2):

Importing `nodeExternals` worked for me.

```
import nodeExternals from 'webpack-node-externals';
```

this is my server.webpack.config:

```
import path from 'path';
import nodeExternals from 'webpack-node-externals'; // changes

const CONTEXT = path.join( __dirname, "../.." ),
  INPUT_SERVER_DIR = path.join( CONTEXT, "server" ),
  OUTPUT_SERVER_DIR = path.join( CONTEXT, "dist/server" );

export default [
  {
    name: 'server',
    target:  'node',
    context: INPUT_SERVER_DIR,
    node: {
      __dirname: false
    },
    entry: './server',
    devtool : 'source-map',
    output: {
      path: OUTPUT_SERVER_DIR,
      filename: "server.js"
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js']
    },
    **externals : [ nodeExternals() ]**
  }
];
```

Comment: Just having webpack-node-externals installed solved the problem for me.

Comment: @JonasKello that was what worked for me too! Thanks for the comment.