# Cannot find module "." at webpackMissingModule

Tags: webpack

This is the error I'm getting:

> Cannot find module "." at webpackMissingModule

This is my webpack.config.js file. How can I find out which line is causing the error? If it is not webpack.config.js that is causing it, may I know what else I should be checking?

```
module.exports = [
  {
    entry: {
      core: './node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js',
      zone: './node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
      reflect: './node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
      system: './node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js'
    },
    output: {
      filename: './wwwroot/js/[name].js'
    },
    target: 'web',
    node: {
      fs: "empty"
    }
  },
  {
    entry: {
      app: './wwwroot/app/main.ts',
      developerlist: './wwwroot/app/developerlist.bootstrap.ts',
      rating: './wwwroot/app/rating.bootstrap.ts'
    },
    output: {
      filename: './wwwroot/js/[name].js'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js']
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
      ]
    }
  }];
```

console.trace:

```
(anonymous) @ VM214:1
webpackMissingModule @ system.js:6179
SystemJSLoader$1 @ system.js:6179
(anonymous) @ system.js:6299
(anonymous) @ system.js:6308
(anonymous) @ system.js:6311
__webpack_require__ @ system.js:20
(anonymous) @ system.js:66
(anonymous) @ system.js:69
VM215:1 console.trace
```

> Error: Cannot find module "." at webpackMissingModule
>   (http://localhost:5000/js/system.js:6179:67) [] at new
>   SystemJSLoader$1 (http://localhost:5000/js/system.js:6179:145)
>   [] at http://localhost:5000/js/system.js:6299:14 [] at
>   Object. (http://localhost:5000/js/system.js:6308:2)
>   [] at Object.
>   (http://localhost:5000/js/system.js:6311:30) [] at
>   **webpack_require** (http://localhost:5000/js/system.js:20:30) [] at http://localhost:5000/js/system.js:66:18 [] at
>   http://localhost:5000/js/system.js:69:10 [] code: "MODULE_NOT_FOUND"

Comment: Can you prive the full error stack trace?

Comment: Added trace, but I'm not sure if it is helpful.

Comment: Did you forget to add the module in the package.json? npm install maybe? This helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34823655/webpack-missing-module-module-not-found

Comment: Note that the error specifies `.` as the missing module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried getting rid of System.js? webpack can do all that System.js can do, there's no point in using a module bundler to bundle a module bundler.

Comment: Except require remote dependencies based on URL at runtime.  As far as I can tell, it can't do that. And in that situation, you might try to use systemjs inside a webpack bundle

Answer (score 1):

My issue was related to react-hot-loader it seems like there is an issue with react router v4, I updated to latest version (a beta version at this time) and it fixed the error

```
"react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.7"
```

by doing a

```
npm install --save-dev react-hot-loader@next
```

Answer (score 1):

> This issue has been resolved in the link below
>
> [Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "."](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4921)

Answer (score 0):

here's the answer that @vin is referring to that works:

```
require('../'+this.state.MainCardPic)
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was the line

```
import { debug } from "webpack";
```

in a react component.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with laravel, and sometimes laravel mix doesn't seem to update changes and still can't find module error shows up continuously after running npm run watch, you should run

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

In my case, it fixed the issue. Also when importing modules try to put .js or .vue or .jsx etc extensions depending on your file. Sometimes webpack doesn't seem to resolve that.

And finally ensure that u provide permissions to the public or dist folder where the webpack is writting the outputs to using

sudo chmod -R 777 public

Answer (score 0):

Had to delete the webpack folder in `server/node_modules/.cache`