# Error: Cannot find module "."

Tags: angular, webpack, socket.io, angular-universal

I'm using Angular Universal, Express with Webpack. I started the application using this git repo:

https://github.com/FrozenPandaz/ng-universal-demo

I cannot seem to use socket.io in my main.server.ts. I can import it, but when trying to setup it up I get an error:

```
...
import * as express from 'express';
import * as socket from 'socket.io';

enableProdMode();
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = socket(server);
// .       ^^ causes error 

app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: ServerAppModule
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', 'src');

app.use('/', express.static('dist', {index: false}));

server.listen(1337);

app.get('test', (req, res) => {
  res.render('../dist/index', {
    req: req,
    res: res
  });
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('register', (data) => {
    socket.join(data);
    user = data;
  });
});
```

The error is happening because of the `socket(server)` call, as if I comment this out the error doesn't happen:

```
/Users/michaelwilson/Code/app/dist/server.js:101828
    return /*require.resolve*/(!(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module \".\""); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }()));
                                                                                                                                            ^

Error: Cannot find module "."
    at webpackMissingModule (/Users/michaelwilson/Code/app/dist/server.js:101828:76)
    at resolvePath (/Users/michaelwilson/Code/app/dist/server.js:101828:154)
    at Server.serveClient (/Users/michaelwilson/Code/app/dist/server.js:101831:25)
    at new Server (/Users/michaelwilson/Code/app/dist/server.js:101770:8)
    at Server (/Users/michaelwilson/Code/app/dist/server.js:101762:41)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/michaelwilson/Code/app/dist/server.js:113993:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/michaelwilson/Code/app/dist/server.js:26:30)
    at /Users/michaelwilson/Code/app/dist/server.js:94:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/michaelwilson/Code/app/dist/server.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I'm not sure what else to try, is this a problem with Webpack + Socket.io? I cannot find anyone else with this same issue...

**Edit:** I have tracked down the line of code this is happening in the socket.io library, its trying to do a dynamic resolve:

```
return /*require.resolve*/(!(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module \".\""); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }()));
```

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34823655/webpack-missing-module-module-not-found
Also, make sure that you have installed those packages that you're referencing correctly (are they in the package.json and in the node_modules folder?)

Comment: @EdmundoRodrigues the error isn't relating to any modules I am referencing, if that was the case it would be within socket.io itself. But the fact it is "." which cannot be found, doesn't seem to be the case...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get rid of this error by setting the `serveClient` property to `false` like so:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  serveClient: false,
  wsEngine: 'ws' // uws is not supported since it is a native module
});
```

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/tree/master/examples/webpack-build-server
https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server-serveclient-value